# Changing a Select dropdown with a jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Trying to set a select dropdown with a slider.  You move the jquery ui slider and then it will change the selection of the other two dropdowns.

is there a current method in jquery that would set these options?

Current dropdown:

```
<select id="alert-options-frequency-opts">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slider has a slide event. Try hooking into that to set the value of the dropdown(s).

e.g

```
$("#slider").slider({
      value:0,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#alert-options-frequency-opts").val(ui.value);
      }
    });
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ejewo3) is a quick demo to get you started